# distance from CurrentLocation to data from Plist File

Tags: iphone, arrays, plist, tableview, cllocation

I have a long list of places with Latitudes and Longitudes in a plist. I want to show a tableView of the places only within X distance of the user's current location. Is there a way to create objects from the lats & longs in the plist file so I can use 'distanceFromLocation'? More importantly, how do I get the array to only display the names with a distance from current less than X? I'm assuming I would need to make a series of objects from lats & longs in the plist, then do an objects in array if objects distanceFrom is less than X, correct?

Please help.

Here's where I am now: I get an error on the double clubLatitude line

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

     NSArray *clubArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self danceClubLocation], nil];
     self.tableData = clubArray;
}

-(CLLocation *)danceClubLocation
{
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSEnumerator *e = [array objectEnumerator];
    id object;
    while ((object = [e nextObject])) {
        double clubLatitude = [[array valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        double clubLongitude = [[array valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocation *clubLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:clubLatitude longitude:clubLongitude];
        if ([clubLocation distanceFromLocation:myLocation]<=50) {
            return clubLocation;
        }
        else return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(CLLocation *)myLocation
{
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    NSNumber *myLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *myLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
    double myLatitudeD = [myLatitude doubleValue];
    double myLongitudeD = [myLongitude doubleValue];
    myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:myLatitudeD longitude:myLongitudeD];
    return myLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidNeiss said, you have to iterate over the list (an NSArray with the plist as source) and it would be something like this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"latlong" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSEnumerator *e = [array objectEnumerator];
id object;
while (object = [e nextObject]) {
  // do something with object
}
```

Then you can do what you want (removing what's far from the user or whatever).

Comment: but coordinates are two objects at once right (lat & long)? how do I enumerate them both? 
What about a different approach, rather than only show the ones less than X distance, would it be easier to just sort all of them by X distance?

If not, I need more help on [e nextObject] above

Comment: [e nextObject] will just iterate over every object in the collection. You can try a number of approaches, from using an NSArray to an NSDictionary, but the iterator part would be the same. Obviously you can sort it before iterating or making the logic inside de while, etcetera.

Comment: by iterate over every object in the collection, you mean entries in my plist file right? How do I tell it to only look at valueforKey @"Latitude" and @"Longitude"? how does *e get displayed when I'm done, as an array? Thanks so much and hopefully I'll stop bugging you now.

Comment: Here you are creating a collection from the plist. You can create an NSArray or an NSDictionary, where you are going to have key/value pairs. e is just an enumerator, it is not displayed, it only purpose is to iterate over the array. Doing the distance calculation is a completely different thing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand it in these terms. I'm too new at this. Can you write a sample? I don't get how *e and nextObject play and the sample code on the developer resources is just for OS X

Comment: Read some documentation then on NSArray, NSEnumerator and so. objectEnumerator is a method from NSArray that returns an NSEnumerator, which you use later on to iterate over the array. And this is the same for OS X then for iOS, is just objecive-c.

Comment: Array's method valueForKey returns another array (an id reference), which you are trying to make into a double. That's the reason of the error. The thing is, i don't know how are you storing the info on the plist, but an NSArray is just an indexed list. Position n, x object. That's it. Then you have an NSSet, which is like a math set and an NSDictionary, which is a hashmap. A key, and a value. Before continuing with this i really recommend you reading more about obj-c collection framework.

Answer (score 0):

Read in your plist, iterate over it to pull out ones within X distance and populate any array with them that will be the data source for your table view?